# Deploying cakePHP app to localhost using XAMPP

Tags: macos, apache, cakephp, xampp

For 3 days I have been trying to get this to work with no luck and it's driving me absolutely insane.  I have used composer to generate a skeleton cakePHP project for me and am now trying to start up the server and test everything is G2G.  From my app directory I run

```
bin/cake server
```

and the following error comes up and does not deploy the app to the server.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_mbstring.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_mbstring.dll, 0x0009): closured error in Unknown on line 0
```

PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.
 in /Users/nateschreiner/Documents/Development/ActTwo/app/config/requirements.php on line 31

I have gone into /etc/php.ini and un-commented

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

and I have also gone into   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini and un-commented the same line.

Nothing is working and it's really starting to grind my gears.  Not getting any help surfing the google either.

Comment: There is probably another ini file used for command line, check that.

Comment: MacOS uses `.so` files, not `.dll` ones, they are for Windows.

Comment: @ndm ok so how do I fix the said issue on a mac or linux OS ?

Comment: Start with commenting the .dll extensions again, and then like @burzum said check whether there are other ini files that your PHP installation uses. Make sure that no ini file points to any .dll extensions. Maybe you haven't installed XAMPP correctly, who knows, but I'd be surprised if XAMPP for MacOS would by default use PHP ini files where .dll extensions are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Took me absolutly forever to solve this, however I finally did so I'll post an answer incase anyone else has this issue.

First:

```
brew install php@7.1
```

( If it's not installed already )

```
brew upgrade php@7.1
```

update symlinks:

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1
```

Then:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After, go to your app directory and issue command:

```
bin/cake server
```

And you should have a server started up on localhost